# Saint-Denis de la Réunion (majuscule et traits d'union)

Tags: majuscules, trait-d-union, toponymes

Comment écrire le nom (ou plutôt le « surnom ») de Saint-Denis, capitale de La Réunion :

- Saint-Denis-de-La Réunion (comme dans ["Cour d'appel de Saint-Denis-de-La Réunion"](https://lannuaire.service-public.fr/la-reunion/reunion/cour_appel-97411-01));
- Saint-Denis-de-La-Réunion (["Tribunal judiciaire de Saint-Denis-de-La-Réunion"](https://lannuaire.service-public.fr/la-reunion/reunion/tgi-97411-01));
- Saint-Denis de la Réunion ([France Diplomatie](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays/maurice/representations-diplomatiques-et-22211/article/saint-denis-de-la-reunion-la-104400));
- Saint-Denis de La Réunion ([France Diplomatie](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays/norvege/representations-diplomatiques-et-consulaires-en-france/article/saint-denis-de-la-reunion-la-104462)).

Merci pour votre aide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En typographie, des traits d'union doivent relier tous les éléments composant le nom officiel d'une entité administrative (sauf article initial et apostrophes).

La ville en question ici s'appelle uniquement « Saint-Denis »; « de la Réunion » n'est qu'une indication géographique qui distingue ce « Saint-Denis » d'autres villes du même nom.

Il faut donc écrire :

> [Saint-Denis de la Réunion](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Denis_(La_R%C3%A9union))

ou, suivant une tendance plus récente<sup>1</sup> :

> [Saint-Denis de **La** Réunion](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Denis_(La_R%C3%A9union))

Quand la suite fait partie du nom officiel, des tirets doivent être utilisés partout comme par exemple :

> [Saint-Denis-d'Oléron](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Denis-d%27Ol%C3%A9ron)
>
> [Saint-Denis-sur-Richelieu](http://Saint-Denis-sur-Richelieu)

---

<sup>1</sup> [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_R%C3%A9union) :

> Conformément à la graphie originelle et aux règles orthographiques et typographiques classiques « la Réunion » s'écrit avec une minuscule à l'article mais, au cours de la fin du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, la graphie « La Réunion » avec une majuscule s'est développée dans de nombreux écrits pour souligner l'intégration de l'article dans le nom. Cette dernière graphie correspond aux préconisations de la Commission nationale de toponymie et figure notamment dans l'actuelle Constitution de la République française aux articles 72-3 et 73.

Comment: Merci. Mais pourquoi « Saint-Denis de la Réunion » et pas « Saint-Denis de La Réunion » comme « Conseil départemental de La Réunion » ?

Comment: Your good analysis of when to use hyphens in place names also seems to apply to other connecting prepositions, as in  “Auvers-sur-Oise” or even more relevant to the question, “Saint-Denis-sur-Richelieu.” I have noticed, however, that when abbreviating “sur[-]” as “s/”, the hyphen also disappears, at least on French road signs (“Auvers-s/Oise”), but I can’t recall ever seeing that abbreviation of “sur” used for “Saint-Denis-sur-Richelieu” (e.g., “Saint-Denis-s/Richelieu”?) on Quebec road signs, either with or without the hyphen.

Comment: @AntoineDusséaux Tout dépends de la nature du « La », si c'est un article: « *Réunion (Île de la)* », « la » reste en minuscule, s'il fait partie du nom « La Réunion », c'est une composante du nom propre et il doit être en majuscule. Historiquement, l'article ne faisait pas partie du nom mais la tendance est à l'intégration. Les deux usages coexistent donc.